# Hold & delay charge transfer to connected account in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-processing, stripe-connect

does anyone have used stripe connect? I want to have feature of hold & transfer charge amount to the connected account i.e. charge should be captured from customer, but keep it on hold for 3/5 days & then transfer it to merchant.
Any information regarding how can i set it in stripe dashboard or through api endpoints would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: do you want to keep charge on hold for 3/5 days while creating it??? or just want to hold transfer to connected account???

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/charges#auth-and-capture might help if you want to keep original charge on hold and release after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `delay_days` of an account when creating it through the API. This is the number of days charges for the account will be held before being paid out:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#account_object-payout_schedule-delay_days

The docs on payout schedules also discuss it in more detail:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#payout-schedule

Comment: Thanks @postmoderngres. It was very helpful to me :)

Comment: But, how to set `delay_days` dynamically? For example, the book appartment today but checkin in a week - so the seller gets paid in a week +24 hours.

Comment: @ekashking did you find the solution?